# Перенос WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Требуется перенести сайт на WordPress. Казалось бы все просто - перенес файлы, в дампе заменил старый домен на новый и все.

Но столкнулся с такой проблемой: WP хранит настройки вот так: `s:21:'http://localhost:8888'`, т.е. s - string, 21 - размер далее следующей строки. При замене `localhost:8888` на новый домен, он не может распарсить эти настройки, т.к. там уже другая длина строки.

Строки могут быть так: `s:99:'asdf sadf localhost:8888 sadf asfd'`.

Как перенести в этом случае?

P.S. Разрабатывал не я. Мне только на хостинг надо вынести.

Comment: Это [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) так упаковывает. Может, распаковать, заменить, упаковать, сохранить?

Answer (score 1):

Распаковать можно через
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

```
$str = file_get_content('file.dat')
$arr = unserialize ( $str )
file_put_content('file.php', var_export($arr, true))
```

Comment: @ALexander, если бы все так просто...
Там в дампе и CREATE TABLE и прочее. Пробую регулярками выбирать и заменять: http://hashcode.ru/questions/297356/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9

Answer (score 1):

define('RELOCATE',true);
в `wp-config.php`
Потом вызвать файл `wp-login.php` в адресной строке общих настроек и сменить домен.
Если вы будете ручками менять сериализацию, то просто сломаете плагин или шаблон.