# Помогите с регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. В виду отсутствия решения для вот этой проблемы: [Перенос Wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/297355/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-wordpress), пишу парсер, который заменит мне параметры по регулярке. Число между : - это длина дальнейшей строки между кавычками. Мне нужно заменить localhost:8888 на свой домен. Длина у него другая и поэтому нужно изменять число.
Имеем строки, например:

```
s:21:"http://localhost:8888";  
s:55:" sd das sd http://localhost:8888 asd as das";s:4:"1234"   
s:2:"rr";s:21:"sd http://localhost:8888 http://localhost:8888 sdaf http://localhost:8888";
```

Я как бы сделал, но при тесте выяснилось, что слишком жадно захватываются строки.

Вот как я ищу:

```
preg_match_all('!s:[0-9]+:".*?localhost:8888*?";!s', $content_file, $old_matches);
```

Но попадают строки типа: s:3:"asd";s:2:"dd";s:21:"http://localhost:8888"; . Она конечно соответствует(s:[число]:"[строка с localhost:8888]"), но как мне выбрать только 
Как мне выбрать минимальные строки? Что-то типа рекурсивного поиска что ли делать?
В идеале нужно запомнить длину [0-9]+ и смотреть, чтоб между кавычками была эта длина. Но не представляю как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

1. Мне кажется, вы выдумали проблему, которую хотите кровь из носа решить при помощи регэкспов.
2. `s55, s2, etc.` - это всё похоже на работу функции `serialize`. Так вот, советую вам для ваших данных сделать `unserialize()`, пройтись по массиву циклом и применить к каждой строке `str_replace('http://localhost:8888', 'mydomen.com', $str)` и после отправить обратно всё в функцию `serialize()`

Comment: @ua6xh, спасибо. Не знал про serialize) Действительно велосипед изобретаю.

Comment: @ua6xh, да, но у меня огромный дамп и мне все равно надо выбирать из него строки, которые содержат localhost и могут сериализоваться. Сериализация особо проблемы не решает. Мне все равно нужно вытаскивать строку s:x:"bla localhost bla"

Comment: Для того, что бы запомнить набор символов, используйте группировку:

preg_match_all('!s:(\d+):".*?localhost:8888*?";!s', $content_file, $old_matches);

\d - это эквивалент набора [0-9]. 

[памятка по реуляркам][1]

[1]: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/e/ee/RegExp_tutorial.png

Comment: @ua6xh, а что мне это группировка даст?

Comment: @ray_ban - в массив old_matches у вас попадет то, что в круглых скобках.

Comment: @ua6xh, так мне не это число не надо. мне нужна исключительно строка s:num:""

Answer (score 0):

я не эксперт в php, но здесь вроде бы можно обойтись без регулярок
[str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace)